# Why is my earlier buttons not working when I created another set of buttons?

Tags: html, css, button

This is the program I am working on, but it seems that when I create another div with button, the buttons at the top seems to not work. I am trying to create a website with buttons in it. What should I do?

```js
function order() {
  location.replace("ORDERSTAB.html");
}

function floorstock() {
  location.replace("FLOORSTOCKSTAB.html");
}

function inventory() {
  location.replace("INVENTORYTAB.html");
}

function statistics() {
  location.replace("STATISTICSTAB.html");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><button class="sidebutton" onclick="order()">ORDERS</button></li>
    <li><button class="sidebutton" onclick="floorstock()">FLOOR STOCK</button></li>
    <li><button class="sidebutton" onclick="inventory()">INVENTORY</button></li>
    <li><button class="sidebutton" onclick="statistics()">STATISITCS</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="category" id="change">CATEGORY</p>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="orderbutton">HOT</button>
  <button class="orderbutton">HOT</button>
  <button class="orderbutton">HOT</button>
  <button class="orderbutton">HOT</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but you need to read the [help] and the [ask] section in particular. You need to provide more details, as it's currently unclear what you're asking

Comment: What is expected behaviour? And why not pass the URL to the function instead of having a function per URL?

Answer (score -1):

your code looks all right and it may be some other problem not related to this chunk of code. And you can easily write some more `divs` and also create some more `buttons` inside of it.
Every button is linked with some function with onclick attribute. So it should work. but if it's not working then

**So here are some reasons it is not working**

- maybe you haven't put that on the script tag.
- or maybe you are using an external file, and you haven't imported it properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).